# Failsafe modification of a JSON file on Linux

Tags: json, linux, database

Serialising JSON to a file is a convenient way for storing arbitrary data structures in a persistent manner. At work, I see this happening a lot, and I think it's understandable to do this instead of using something like SQLite because it's just so damn easy.

The problem with this is that when you modify the file programmatically, you might end up corrupting the file and you might lose your data or the software might be unable to proceed after the data has been corrupted. E.g. the file could be only partially written due to an abrupt power failure or a crash. Also, if there are multiple processes modifying the file, it will need some locking, but this is rarely the case.

A few years back, I came up with what I believe is a failsafe approach to modifying JSON files on Linux, but I am not a database expert and people say that "you should never write your own database". Thus, I'd appreciate some feedback from database experts on the matter. Is this really a failsafe approach?

For the single consumer, single producer case, it goes like this:

1. Read the JSON file and parse it
2. Change a node in the object tree
3. Serialise the new object tree to a file on the same file system.

   - E.g. if the path to the old file is `/etc/example/config.json` then the new file should be at `/etc/example/config.json.tmp`.
   - It's important to keep the temporary file on the same filesystem, and not on e.g. `/tmp` because this makes the `rename()` system call atomic with regard to filesystem operations.
   - This means that after a `rename()`, the file is guaranteed to be complete.
   - If the system experiences a power failure at the time of `rename()` the change may be lost but the old file will still be complete and not corrupted.
4. Run `fdatasync()` or `fsync()` on the new file.

   - This can take a while. Don't run this in the main loop.
   - When this call returns, the file is guaranteed to have been written to persistent storage
5. (optional) Read the new file and verify that it's valid JSON and that it fits the schema
6. Rename the new file to the name of the old file using the `rename()` system call

We almost never share files between processes but in the multiple producers case, one might use something like `flock()`, but read-locks are not necessary because of the `rename()` logic described above. The file is guaranteed to always be complete.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: Bullet 3 sounds like so called "atomic save" approach. Some OSes, Windows included, and spome fs drivers support that across file systems. Windows even preserves timestamps of old file when it gets replaced.